# Little indentations on tea plant

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, diseases, fungus, tea

[image: leaf]

I spotted these on 2 new leaves of my camellia sinensis, the other leaves don't have these at all, its inside against a western facing window, watered every 4 days fertilized every 2nd month, I want it to grow out a bit before I start harvesting

I can't find anything online that looks like that,

maybe I'm overreacting but if its something bad I want to nip it in the bud as fast as possible

Update: underside of the leaf doesn't look black I can't see anything in there just looks like the leaf itself has bumps
[image: under]

Comment: Those could be places where insects poked through the leaf tissue and laid eggs inside. If that's the case, there will likely be visible bumps on the underside of the leaf. Can you check for those and update your question accordingly? (A photo of the underside of the leaf would be helpful, too.)